# XSLT - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm receiving this error:

```
2020-04-01 09:25:29.8519 [64] AN2PRER57BJE004:BJE_ustestr57  ERROR SharpTop.DataServices.Platform.Export.ExportHelper - Exception in ProcessXSLT() - ExportHelper class: 
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(Stream stream)
at SharpTop.DataServices.Platform.Export.ExportHelper.ProcessXSLT(ExportResult result, 
DataExportDefinition dataExportDefinion) in d:\_wf\01\1\s\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\ExportFramework\ExportHelper.cs:line 76
2020-04-01 09:25:29.8519 [64] AN2PRER57BJE004:BJE_ustestr57  INFO SharpTop.Engine.BackgroundJobs.PayRunExportBase - XSLT transformation for USA failed.
```

This issue is usually because of a space, but I truly don't know what's wrong with the code, I've been looking at it for about 16 hours to no avail.  Can anyone see the problem?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:cs="urn:cs">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- Header -->
<!-- Col. 01 JournalID-->
<xsl:text>jrnlid,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 02 JournalLine -->
<xsl:text>jrnlline,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 03 BatchID-->
<xsl:text>batchid,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 04 Account -->
<xsl:text>acct,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 05 TransactionDate-->
<xsl:text>trnsdt,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 06 Description -->
<xsl:text>desc,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 07 Amount-->
<xsl:text>amt,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 08 Reversal -->
<xsl:text>reversal,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 09 GLType-->
<xsl:text>gltype,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 10 CurrencyType -->
<xsl:text>crnctype,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 11 PR-->
<xsl:text>pr</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<!-- Details -->
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[Amt!=0]">
<!-- Col. 01 JournalID-->
<xsl:text>RJ-27,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 02 JournalLine -->
<xsl:number format="000001"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 03 BatchID-->
<xsl:text>BWP,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 04 Account -->
<xsl:value-of select="concat('01',location,acct,department,'00',substring(empno,2,4))"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 05 TransactionDate-->
<xsl:value-of select="trnsdt"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 06 Description-->
<xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 07 Amount-->
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="amt &lt; 0">
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(amt * -1,"0.00")'/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:text/>
<!-- Col. 08  Reversal-->
<xsl:text>N,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 09 GLType-->
<xsl:text>C,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 10 CurrencyType -->
<xsl:text>USD,</xsl:text>
<!-- Col. 11 PR-->
<xsl:text>PR</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The error might be caused when trying to parse the input document so ceck or post that as well.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, there is no debug information recorded by the system, I only have the parameters used and the job information, which the error came into the latter, which is posted.  I have put my code in online validators/checkers and now received an error message, so not sure where/what to do.  FYI, I've self taught myself XSLT only in the last two weeks, so am a complete noob.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - that means the input too.